# Difference between dask node and compute node for slurm configuration

Tags: slurm, dask-distributed, dask-jobqueue

First off, apologies if I use confusing or incorrect terminology, I am still learning.

I am trying to set up configuration for a Slurm-enabled adaptive cluster.

Documentation of the supercomputer and it’s Slurm configuration is documented [here](https://docs.dkrz.de/doc/levante/running-jobs/partitions-and-limits.html#). Here is some of the most relevant information extracted from the website:

| **Partition Name** | **Max Nodes per Job** | **Max Job Runtime** | **Max resources used simultaneously** | **Shared Node Usage** | **Default Memory per CPU** | **Max Memory per CPU** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **compute** | 512 | 8 hours | no limit | no | 1920 MB | 8000 MB |

### compute

This partition consists of **2659** AMD EPYC 7763 Milan compute nodes and is intended for running parallel scientific applications. The compute nodes allocated for a job are used exclusively and cannot be shared with other jobs. Some information about the [compute node](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-epyc-7763):

| Component | Value |
| --- | --- |
| **# of CPU Cores** | 64 |
| **# of Threads** | 128 |

Here is some output from `control show partition`:

```
PartitionName=compute
   AllowGroups=ALL AllowAccounts=ALL AllowQos=ALL
   AllocNodes=ALL Default=NO QoS=N/A
   DefaultTime=NONE DisableRootJobs=NO ExclusiveUser=NO GraceTime=0 Hidden=NO
   MaxNodes=512 MaxTime=08:00:00 MinNodes=0 LLN=NO MaxCPUsPerNode=UNLIMITED
   Nodes=l[10000-10058,10061-10062,10064-10065,10067-10068,10070-10083,10090-10095,10100-10158,10160-10183,10190-10195,10200-10258,10260-10283,10290-10295,10300-10357,10359-10383,10390-10395,10400-10483,10490-10495,10500-10583,10590-10595,10600-10683,10690-10695,10700-10783,10790-10795,20000-20059,20061-20062,20064-20065,20067-20068,20070-20083,20090-20095,20100-20183,20190-20195,20200-20223,20225-20283,20290-20295,20300-20383,20390-20395,20400-20483,20490-20495,20500-20583,20590-20595,20600-20683,20690-20695,30000-30059,30061-30062,30064-30083,30090-30095,30100-30183,30190-30195,30200-30230,30232-30283,30290-30295,30300-30383,30390-30395,30400-30483,30490-30495,30500-30583,30590-30595,30600-30683,30690-30695,30700-30760,30762-30783,30790-30795,40000-40026,40028-40029,40031-40032,40034-40035,40037-40038,40040-40083,40090-40095,40101-40102,40104-40105,40107-40108,40110-40111,40113-40183,40190-40195,40200-40283,40287-40295,40300-40359,40400-40483,40490-40495,40500-40583,40587-40595,40600-40683,40687-40695,50200-50259,50269-50271,50300-50359,50369-50371]
   PriorityJobFactor=1 PriorityTier=1 RootOnly=NO ReqResv=NO OverSubscribe=EXCLUSIVE
   OverTimeLimit=NONE PreemptMode=OFF
   State=UP TotalCPUs=711168 TotalNodes=2778 SelectTypeParameters=NONE
   JobDefaults=(null)
   DefMemPerCPU=960 MaxMemPerCPU=3840
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
cluster = SLURMCluster(
    name='dask-cluster', 
    processes=32,
    cores=64,
    memory=f"{8000 * 64 * 0.90} MB",
    project="ab0995",
    queue="compute",
    interface='ib0',
    walltime='08:00:00',
    asynchronous=0,
    # job_extra=["--ntasks-per-node=50",],
)
```

Some things to mention:

1. In the first above table, “nodes” refers to compute server nodes, not Dask nodes (which I think should probably be rather called Dask Workers? If someone could clear up that term for me I would be grateful). Since I have 64 CPU Cores and 8000 MB of allowed memory, I thought it would be sensible to set the memory to `8000 * 64` with a “reduction” factor of `0.90`, just to be on the safe side.
2. I have 64 CPUs, which I believe should translate to 64 “`cores`” in the `SLURMCluster`. I want each Python to have 2 CPUs, so, in total 32 processes. That might be optimised down to 4 CPUs per Python, but I have no idea how to get a feeling for sensible settings here.
3. I set the walltime of each `dask-cluster` job to the maximum allowed; as I would rather block with one Slurm Job than need to wait. This might induce idle work of that server, but it might still be more effective than waiting in the Slurm batch system queue.

If I now print the job script as configured above, I get:

```
print(cluster.job_script())

#!/usr/bin/env bash

#SBATCH -J dask-worker
#SBATCH -p compute
#SBATCH -A ab0995
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=64
#SBATCH --mem=430G
#SBATCH -t 08:00:00

/work/ab0995/AWIsoft/miniconda/NextGEMS/.conda/bin/python -m distributed.cli.dask_worker tcp://136.172.120.121:36449 --nthreads 2 --nprocs 32 --memory-limit 13.41GiB --name dummy-name --nanny --death-timeout 60 --interface ib0 --protocol tcp://
```

So, questions:

1. By my mental math, `8000*64*0.9 = 460.8 GB`, not `430G` What is happening here?
2. I don’t really understand the `nthreads`. `nprocs`, and `memory-limit` getting of the `dask_worker`…?
3. Can someone give me a good distinction between dask nodes, dask workers, compute nodes as seen in slurm?

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation to yours, where I am trying to understand how dask-ditributed works with Slurms.

1. The dask-distributed [docs](https://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/configuration-setup.html#gigabyte-vs-gibibyte) report that Slurm uses KB or GB, but it actually means KiB or GiB, so Dask converts your value in GiB.

2. What I've found is that `nprocs=processes`, `nthreads=cores/processes` and `memory-limit=allocated-memory/processes`. The job will then launch a `dask_worker` using `nprocs` processes of `nthreads` each (which will be the Workers of your SLURMCluster).
3. This is not clear to me as well, so I don't have a good answer. I think that since Slurm nodes have several CPUs, the Scheduler of your SLURMCluster manages Dask Workers based on the allocated CPUs. (I didn't find anything about dask nodes from the docs though)